# Best way to handle complicated nested data using Perl

Tags: perl, nested-datalist

I am relatively new to programming. I have to process a massive file containing nested data on married couples like below.  I tried to use writing a program in Perl but setting up so many flags to go into each of the nested data beginning { and ending with } does not seem like an efficient way to process this data.  I am seeking your advice on how to best handle data like below in Perl.

Thanks a ton.
Andy

I have some data that looks like below:

```
city{
 area : 50 sq miles ;
 population : 3000 ;
 healthIndex : 90.5/100 ;

 marriedCouples { //this begins one married couple data
  children : 2 ;
  chronologicalData() {
   date: 02-10-1990 ;
   incomeRising("TableVals") {
    values("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9") ;
   }
   incomeFalling("TableVals") {
    values("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9") ;
   }
  }
  child {
   name: Nathan;
   chronologicalData() {
     DOB: 02-13-1994 ;

    incomeRising("TableVals") {
     values("0 2 2 3 4 9 6 7 8 9") ;
    }
    incomeFalling("TableVals") {
     values("0 1 2 1 1 1 6 7 8 9") ;
    }
   }
   intrinsicVal() {
    risingVals {
     values("0 0.1 0.33 0.34 0.6 0.9 0.11 0.123 0.14 0.15") ;
    }
    fallingVals {
     values("0.15 0.10 0.09 0.08 0.08 0.078 0.75 0.6 0.5 0.4") ;
    }
   }
  }
 } // this finishes one married couple data

  child {  //Note that this child is not within the married couple and is a stand-alone child. It is outside of it
   name: Cody;
   chronologicalData() {
     DOB: 02-13-1974 ;

    incomeRising("TableVals") {
     values("0 12 22 33 44 49 56 57 58 59") ;
    }
    incomeFalling("TableVals") {
     values("0 41 32 21 21 19 18 17 16 15") ;
    }
   }
   intrinsicVal() {
    risingVals {
     values("0 0.1 0.331 0.34 0.6 0.9 0.11 0.123 0.14 0.125") ;
    }
    fallingVals {
     values("0.55 0.10 0.09 0.08 0.08 0.078 0.75 0.6 0.5 0.4") ;
    }
   }
  } // End stand alone child
} // End city data
```

Comment: Are these data in some standard format? Your sample looks rather like JSON. If so check out [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) and search for a module designed to handle the data. If the format is JSON, perhaps [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm) will make your life easier.

Comment: Do you have access to the program that created the file? It may document the format and offer some clues as to how it should be read.

Comment: If you have access to the program that created the file, and can choose the data format to export, you can choose JSON, XML or YAML, any of which have libraries which will allow data to be imported directly with its structure intact. If the exporting program is written in Perl, it may allow the use of `Data::Dumper`, which would generate perl code very similar to +Mekk's second solution below.

Answer (score 0):

If this is task you may do repeatably, I would consider writing simple parser for this mini-language. Doesn't seem to be very hard even from scratch, https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::RecDescent may be of some use (if not overkill).

If I were in a hurry, had to handle such file once, and this file would be below 100MB, I would .... open a copy of that in emacs and make a few regexp replaces to make it correct perl by itself (or, if the file is very big, wrote short script to make those regexp replacemnets). That's not far, sth like:

```
city => {
    area => "50 sq miles",
    marriedCouples => { # this begins one married couple data
       children => 2, 
       #...
       values => qw(0 0.1 0.331 0.34 0.6 0.9 0.11 0.123 0.14 0.125),
    },
```

is proper perl, so changes like

- swap :(anything);  with => "(anything)",
- add , after every }
- make qw out of ("...")

will go close...